# Access to WrappedArray elements

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe and here is the schema:

```
|-- eid: long (nullable = true)
|-- age: long (nullable = true)
|-- sex: long (nullable = true)
|-- father: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
```

and a sample of rows:.

```
df.select(df['father']).show()
+--------------------+
|              father|
+--------------------+
|[WrappedArray(-17...|
|[WrappedArray(-11...|
|[WrappedArray(13,...|
+--------------------+
```

and the type is

```
DataFrame[father: array<array<bigint>>]
```

How can I have access to each element of inner array? For example -17 in the first row?
I tried different things like `df.select(df['father'])(0)(0).show()` but no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, the syntax for in Python is

```
df.select(df['father'])[0][0].show()
```

or

```
df.select(df['father']).getItem(0).getItem(0).show()
```

See some examples here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=column#pyspark.sql.Column

Answer (score 3):

The solution in scala should be as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val data =  sparkContext.parallelize("""{"eid":1,"age":30,"sex":1,"father":[[1,2]]}""" :: Nil)
val dataframe = sqlContext.read.json(data).toDF()
```

the dataframe looks as

```
+---+---+---+--------------------+
|eid|age|sex|father              |
+---+---+---+--------------------+
|1  |30 |1  |[WrappedArray(1, 2)]|
+---+---+---+--------------------+
```

the solution should be

```
dataframe.select(col("father")(0)(0) as("first"), col("father")(0)(1) as("second")).show(false)
```

output should be

```
+-----+------+
|first|second|
+-----+------+
|1    |2     |
+-----+------+
```

Comment: why do you wrap your column with the `array` function? `dataframe.select($"father"(0)(0))` or   `dataframe.select(col("father")(0)(0))` also works just fine

Answer (score 1):

Another scala answer would look like this:

```
df.select(col("father").getItem(0) as "father_0", col("father").getItem(1) as "father_1")
```