# pandas dataframe how to convert object to array and extract the array value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame as below which I received from hive DB.

How to extract value 'cat', 'animal', and 'dog' in column `col2`.

```
In[]:
sample = {'col1': ['cat', 'dog'], 'col2': ['WrappedArray([animal], [cat])', 'WrappedArray([animal], [dog])']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=sample)
df

out[] :
    col1                            col2
-----------------------------------------
0   cat     WrappedArray([animal], [cat])
1   dog     WrappedArray([animal], [dog])
```

I tried to convert object to an array and extract the data like this code.

```
In[]: df['col2'][0][1]
Out[]: cat
```

If this is wrong, which way can I go for, I'm new to Pandas so the question might be unclear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the "WrappedArray()" coming from?  Is that how you're getting the data?  I'm guessing you're not actually creating a dataset like that, you'd just be making more work for yourself.

Comment: @elPastor yes, I didn't create the dataframe, it's what I received from database.

Comment: How did you read the data from the database?

Comment: Not sure that this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44468311/access-to-wrappedarray-elements. Looks like `WrappedArray` is spark type.

Comment: @TomRon its selected data. The column has consisted of an array. This is how the column type : col1 array<struct<tag:string,score:float>>

Comment: @Poojan Thank you. However, I googled all relevant to 'WrappedArray', extract array value and I couldn't apply in my code.

Comment: I tried this way that removes 'WrappedArray' and made the value simple as 'animal, dog'. And, df['array'] = df['col2'].str.split(',').
Thought, is hard this data convert into an array?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], we need an accurate picture of your code and data.

Comment: @AMC Thank you for letting me know the page. I will carefully mind it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data in the second column `col2` appear to be simply strings.

The output from `df['col2'][0][1]` would be `"r"` Which is the second character (index 1) in the first string. To get `"cat"` you would need to alter the strings and remove the `'WrappedArray([animal]...'` stuff. leaving only the actual data. "cat", "dog', etc.

You could try `df['col2'].iloc[0][24:27]`, but that's not a general solution. It would also be brittle and unmaintainable.

If you have any control over how the data is exported from the database, try to get the data out in a cleaner format, i.e. without the `WrappedArray(...` stuff.

**Regular expressions might be helpful here.**

You could try something like this:

```py
import re

wrapped = re.compile(r'\[(.*?)\].+\[(.*?)\]')
element = wrapped.search(df['col2'].iloc[0]).group(2)
```

*** Danger Danger Danger ***

If you need that functionality. You could create a `WrappedArray` function that returns the contents as list of strings or the like. Then you can call it by using `eval(df['col2'][0][1])`.

Don't do this.

**FYI:**

Your dtypes likely defaulted to object, because you didn't specify them when you created your data frame. You can do that like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data=sample, dtype='string')
```

Also, it's recommended to use iloc to index dataframes by index.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it as @rkedge advised me

the data is written in a foreign language.

As I said, DataFrame has object data written with 'WrappedArray([우주ごぎゅ],[ぎゃ],[한국어])'.

```
df_ = df['col2'].str.extractall(r'([REGEX expression]+)')
df_

0   0   우주ごぎゅ
0   1   ぎゃ
0   2   한국어
1   0   cat
2   0   animal
```